# Does this function correspond to some inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, machine-learning

Suppose I have $m$ vectors $\mathbf{x_1}, \mathbf{x_2}, ... \mathbf{x_m} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Each vector is divided into 3 parts, e.g. $\mathbf{x_i} = (\mathbf{y_i}, \mathbf{z_i}, \mathbf{w_i})$ where $\mathbf{y_i} \in \mathbb{R}^{n_1}$, $\mathbf{z_i} \in \mathbb{R}^{n_2}$, $\mathbf{w_i} \in \mathbb{R}^{n_3}$ and $n_1 + n_2 + n_3 = n$.

Consider the function $K(\mathbf{x_i}, \mathbf{x_j}) = \mathbf{y_i} \cdot \mathbf{y_j} + \mathbf{z_i} \cdot \mathbf{z_j} + \mathbf{w_i} \cdot \mathbf{w_j}$. It can be verified that $K$ satisfies the [3 axioms of an inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition) (in fact, $K(\mathbf{x_i}, \mathbf{x_j}) = \mathbf{x_i} \cdot \mathbf{x_j}$).

However, suppose $K$ is instead defined as $K(\mathbf{x_i}, \mathbf{x_j}) = (\mathbf{y_i} \cdot \mathbf{y_j})(\mathbf{z_i} \cdot \mathbf{z_j} + \mathbf{w_i} \cdot \mathbf{w_j})$. $K$ still satisfies the symmetry requirement, but no longer satisfies axioms (2) and (3).

Here is my question: does there exist a mapping $\phi$ under which $K$ corresponds to an inner product, e.g. $K(\mathbf{x_i}, \mathbf{x_j}) = \langle \phi(\mathbf{x_i}), \phi(\mathbf{x_j}) \rangle$? If not, can you prove otherwise?

Comment: Is it even true for $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $\mathbf{y_i},\,\mathbf{z_i},\,\mathbf{w_i}$ one-dimensional vectors?

Comment: @mr_e_man This is related to the kernel trick, which is what I'm trying to use it for.

Comment: @JamesKo -- Actually, I don't know anything about machine learning. It just looked irrelevant.

Comment: @JamesKo -- After reading a bit about it, I see it is relevant.

Comment: Is there a requirement that $\phi$ be a bijection?

Comment: I suspect the difficult part will be satisfying $<ax_1,y_1>=a<x_1,y_1>$.

Answer (score 1):

Define
\begin{equation}
K(\mathbf{x_i}, \mathbf{x_j}) = (\mathbf{y_i} \cdot \mathbf{y_j})(\mathbf{z_i} \cdot \mathbf{z_j} + \mathbf{w_i} \cdot \mathbf{w_j})
\end{equation}
Suppose there exists a mapping $\phi$ satisfying
\begin{equation}
K(\mathbf{x_i}, \mathbf{x_j}) = \langle \phi(\mathbf{x_i}), \phi(\mathbf{x_j}) \rangle
\end{equation}
A desirable property for such a $\phi$ would be that for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$
\begin{equation}
\phi(\alpha\mathbf{x})=\alpha^2\phi(\mathbf{x})
\end{equation}
since for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ we have
\begin{equation}
K(\alpha\mathbf{x_i}, \mathbf{x_j})=\langle \phi(\alpha\mathbf{x_i}), \phi(\mathbf{x_j}) \rangle
\end{equation}
Also, it is the case that
\begin{eqnarray}
K(\alpha\mathbf{x_i}, \mathbf{x_j}) &=& (\alpha\mathbf{y_i} \cdot \mathbf{y_j})(\alpha\mathbf{z_i} \cdot \mathbf{z_j} + \alpha\mathbf{w_i} \cdot \mathbf{w_j})\\
&=&\alpha^2 (\mathbf{y_i} \cdot \mathbf{y_j})(\mathbf{z_i} \cdot \mathbf{z_j} + \mathbf{w_i} \cdot \mathbf{w_j})\\
&=&\alpha^2 \langle \phi(\mathbf{x_i}), \phi(\mathbf{x_j}) \rangle
\end{eqnarray}
Therefore
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle \phi(\alpha\mathbf{x_i}), \phi(\mathbf{x_j}) \rangle&=&\alpha^2 \langle \phi(\mathbf{x_i}), \phi(\mathbf{x_j}) \rangle\\
&=&\langle \alpha^2\phi(\mathbf{x_i}), \phi(\mathbf{x_j}) \rangle
\end{eqnarray}
This would follow provided 
\begin{equation}
\phi(\alpha\mathbf{x_i})=\alpha^2\phi(\mathbf{x_i})
\end{equation}
This leaves open the question of whether such a $\phi$ exists.

Note that whereas 
$$ \langle \phi(\alpha\mathbf{x_i}), \phi(\mathbf{x_j}) \rangle=\langle \alpha^2\phi(\mathbf{x_i}), \phi(\mathbf{x_j}) \rangle $$
does not imply that
$$ \phi(\alpha\mathbf{x_i})=\alpha^2\phi(\mathbf{x_i}) $$
it does imply that

$$ \vert \phi(\alpha\mathbf{x})\vert=\alpha^2\vert\phi(\mathbf{x})\vert $$

if $\phi$ is real-valued, since

\begin{eqnarray}
\vert\phi(\alpha\mathbf{x})\vert^2&=&\langle\phi(\alpha\mathbf{x}),\phi(\alpha\mathbf{x})\rangle\\
&=&\langle\alpha^2\phi(\mathbf{x}),\phi(\alpha\mathbf{x})\rangle\\
&=&\alpha^2\langle\phi(\alpha\mathbf{x}),\phi(\mathbf{x})\rangle\\
&=&\alpha^2\langle\alpha^2\phi(\mathbf{x}),\phi(\mathbf{x})\rangle\\
&=&\alpha^4\langle\phi(\mathbf{x}),\phi(\mathbf{x})\rangle\\
&=&\alpha^4\vert\phi(\mathbf{x})\vert^2
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: This would imply that $\phi(-\vec x) = \phi(\vec x)$, and that $\phi(\vec 0) = \vec 0$.

Comment: @mr_e_man Yes, it would.

Comment: But is this a necessary condition? Does the last equation follow from the previous equation? I think it does, because the previous one must be true for all $\vec x_j$.

Comment: Then again, the OP hasn't specified the number $m$ of vectors, so there may not be enough $\vec x_j$s.

Comment: @mr_e_man  No, it's only necessary that $\langle \phi(\alpha\mathbf{x_i}), \phi(\mathbf{x_j}) \rangle=\langle \alpha^2\phi(\mathbf{x_i}), \phi(\mathbf{x_j}) \rangle$.

Comment: But is it necessary if there are enough $\vec x_j$s? If, for all $\vec z$, $\vec x\cdot\vec z = \vec y\cdot\vec z$, does it follow that $\vec x = \vec y$?

Comment: @mr_e_man Yes, that would follow. If it's true for all $\vec{z}$ then it's true for all the vectors $\vec{i_p}$ of a basis, so each coordinate of $\vec{x}$ in the basis would equal the corresponding coordinate of $\vec{y}$ in the basis.